# How to split one liner object keys to multiple lines - so each key will has its own line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this:

```
method({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
```

I want to find the magic key in VSCode that turns it to this:

```
method({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
});
```

And vice versa